# Set up an R ggarrange plot (x, y axis and legend text size)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Ia am trying to set up an array of plots with the ggarrange package.

I assigned a specific color to each element in the 'carrier' column, and used a loop to create a donut chart for each element in the 'origin' column.
Finally, with ggarrange, I constructed a plots array and set up a single legend for the three plots.

```
#install.packages("nycflights13")
library(nycflights13)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggpubr)

#create a color palette and assign a color to each value in "carrier"
colors <- my_colors[1:length(unique(flights$carrier))]
col_by_carrier <- setNames(colors, unique(flights$carrier))

# Vector whith the values
codigos <- c("EWR", "JFK", "LGA")

# create a donut chart for each "origin"
for (i in codigos) {
  # filtering just one "origin"
  data <- flights %>%
    filter(origin == i) %>%
    group_by(carrier) %>%
    summarize(counts = n()) %>%
    mutate(percentage = counts / sum(counts) * 100)
  
  # create and save plots
  plot_name <- paste("A_", i, sep = "")
  assign(plot_name, ggplot(data = data, aes(x = 2, y = percentage, fill = carrier)) +
           geom_col(color = "black") +
           coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
           theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
                 axis.line = element_blank(),
                 axis.text = element_blank(),
                 axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                 axis.title = element_blank()) +
           scale_fill_manual(values = col_by_carrier) +
           xlim(0.5, 2.5) +
           annotate(geom = 'text', x = 0.5, y = 0.5, label = as.character(i), size = 8, fontface = "bold") +
           theme(legend.position = "none"))
}

#create an arrange of plots with a common legend
ggarrange( A_EWR,
           A_JFK,
           A_LGA,
           col =  1,
           common.legend = TRUE,
           legend = "right",
           nrow = 1)
```

I have tried many ways to:
1- Increase the font size of the labels.
2- Insert text on the X-axis and Y-axis."

I tried to set up with ggplots using "+ theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 20))" and many another ways but it was impossible

I got the plot, but I cannot set up axis y and X and I cannot change the text size of legend

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall an easier way to create your plot would be to use facetting instead of creating separate plots. Doing so allows to set the font size for the legend text using `theme` options. Concerning your issue with the axis text I a not sure what's your desired result. Especially as you removed the axis, text and title via theme options.

```r
library(nycflights13)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

# Vector whith the values
codigos <- c("EWR", "JFK", "LGA")

data <- flights %>%
  filter(origin %in% codigos) %>%
  group_by(origin, carrier) %>%
  summarize(counts = n()) %>%
  mutate(percentage = counts / sum(counts) * 100)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'origin'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.

data_label <- data %>%
  distinct(origin)

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = 2, y = percentage, fill = carrier)) +
  geom_col(color = "black") +
  geom_text(
    data = data_label, aes(label = origin, fill = NULL),
    x = 0.5, y = 0.5, size = 8, fontface = "bold"
  ) +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  xlim(0.5, 2.5) +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_blank(),
    # axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    strip.text.x = element_blank(),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 20)
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~origin)
```

[image]